# how to set a confirm box with picture(javascript)

Tags: javascript

In Chrome web store, when I add a new application, there is a confirm box with a picture (App icon) to ask me.
I have tried to search the JavaScript code to find the answer but there is no result.

Is it created by JavaScript API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using Chrome-webapp-specific code: [Inline Installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation)

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"
    href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[app-id]">
```

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.webstore.install();
});
```

This will not work on non-validated webpages nor browsers other than Chrome, since it is not part of [normative JavaScript (ECMAScript) spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

If you are planning to implement a confirmation box with images in your website, try [jQuery UI's modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).